# Jquery slider with fixed values set both handle values

Tags: jquery, slider

Hello everyone I am using jquery slider with fixed values made of array like this

```
valMap = [3000,5000,6000];    

jQuery("#range_slider_1").slider({

                min: 0,
                max: valMap.length - 1,
                values: [0,1],
                slide: function(event, ui) {                        

                }       
});
```

and i Would like to set my both handles by my own values. I Tried this

```
jQuery("#range_slider_1").slider("values",0,"3000"); 
jQuery("#range_slider_1").slider("values",1,"5000");
```

but it just does not work correctly

here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/6ngdH/

Comment: `jQuery("#range_slider_2").slider("values",0,"3000")` it should be `jQuery("#range_slider_1")` i guess .

Comment: Sorry :D miss typed number

Comment: can u make a fiddle ?

Comment: Check answer your problem solved .

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't set `max` value properly. As per your code it's `2`. Because you are calculating the length of array and then subtracting 1, i.e 2.

Replace this line `max: valMap.length - 1,` with whatever value you want. For example:

```
max: valMap[2],
```

In your case, your maximum value is 2 and you are trying to set a value greater than that,that's why it's not working.

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/6ngdH/1/

Answer (score 0):

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/vYH25/)

```
max: valMap[valMap.length - 1], //you need to get last value of array
```

---

Or

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/vYH25/1)

[.pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

```
max: valMap.pop(), //use .pop() to get last value of array
```

---

**Problem**

You are not setting value of the `max` value correctly.

`max: valMap.length - 1,` which sets value to `3-1` which `2`

When max value is set to `2` you can not set value greater than max value .